# Missing DLL "arcore-camera-utility" when building for arm 64bit (works for 32bit)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

My AR app was running fine and in the Google play store but I had to make a couple of small UI tweaks and when I tried to update in the store I ran into the new 64bit requirement. I was able to re-install all the third-party Unity libraries I was using to fix almost all of it except one DLL issue. Everything works great in the il2cpp built arm 32bit version but if I add support for 64bit it breaks. AR sort of works but object placement is way off.

If I click on the "libarcore_camera_utility.so", from the Assets\GoogleARCore\Examples\ComputerVision\Plugins directory, in the Unity editor it lets me pick which CPU to target 32/64, (not both for some reason) I can switch it to 64 but I still get the DLL not found error even though it appears to be in the right directory in the APK. (I've also tried moving the file to Assets\Plugins\Android\libs (both arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a) and still get the DLL error if I include 64 bit as a target. (Everything works great if only 32 bit is selected)

If I run logcat on the 64bit version that is breaking I get the error:

DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'arcore_camera_utility': The specified module could not be found.
   at UnityARInterface.ARCoreInterface.TextureReader_create (Int32 format, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean keepAspectRatio) [0x00000] in 
   at UnityARInterface.ARCoreInterface+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in 
   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in :0

The file "arcore_camera_utility.so" seems to be the culprit because if I build for 32bit only and remove this file I get the same error message and behavior as the 64bit version.

Comment: you have the 64bit version of the dll?

Comment: So, the .so library file was part of this release: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases/tag/v1.5.0 which does specifically mention 64bit support: "Added ARM 64 support." Having said that, if I view the arcore_camera_utility.so file in Unity the inspection panel shows that it defaults to 32bit. So it does seem like there's an issue there. It also contains the source, should I be using NDK to compile my own 64bit library or something? It seems like the unity build process and grable/il2cpp has handled this for everything else?

Comment: i think you will need to build it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I did, in fact, need to compile it myself as Proxytype suggested in comments. I have full instructions for how-to compile yourself in the answer to this question: [How do I build the arcore camera_utility shared library in NDK-BUILD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195077/how-do-i-build-the-arcore-camera-utility-shared-library-in-ndk-build)